# Jmeter request consecutive inter nodes

Tags: java, jmeter

In Jmeter is it possible:

> ```
> Slave Node 1 = > Thread 1,2,3
> Slave Node 2 = > Thread 4,5,6
> ```

Request Queue: t0 thread1, t0+30 second thread4, t0+60 second thread2, t0+90 second thread 5...

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? What is the issue here? What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

In JMeter only following setup is possible:

```
Slave Node 1 = > Thread 1,2,3
Slave Node 2 = > Thread 1,2,3
```

Threads (virtual users) arrival can be controlled using [Ramp-up period](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide/) of setting of normal [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) or via [Custom Thread Groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups)

If you want users on different slaves to execute different tasks - you can specify the tasks via [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) on each slave or use [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) in combination with [__machineName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName) or [__machineIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) functions so certain Samplers would be executed only on certain slave machines